# Me.Activate() is not working on some PC's

Tags: vb.net

I'm working with SHDocVw.InternetExplorer in my VB.NET form (clicks in IE window).
Then I have to get focus back to my form, did it by:

```
Me.Activate()
```

On my developer PC this works fine, but on another PC form does not activate - just blinks at the windows taskbar.
Tried to use SetForegroundWindow (iser32) method with no luck too.
Why does not work Me.Activate on another PC?

Comment: If your application is not active (another program has focus -- not just another form), you will see the flashing.

Comment: ok, but on my developer PC this works...

Comment: What versions of windows are you observing the different behaviours on?

Comment: In windows 8, blinking on the taskbar would be the expected behaviour.  The real question is why it's re-focussing on _your_ PC.  It's a case of "what if every application did this" - they'd all be fighting to be on top, hence the change in later versions of windows to only blink on the taskbar.

Comment: I think its due to debug mode, but when I run exe behind VS (not in debug mode) it works fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved another way:

```
Me.TopMost = True
```

and then when I have to activate my form I use mouse click emulation by mouse_event (user32).